# Payflow recurring with hosted checkout pages

Tags: php, paypal, recurring-billing, payflowpro

I want to integrate the recurring with payflow (with hosted pages on paypal) for my client. But I didn't find tutorial or sample code in php for the same.

Beside this I am also not able to get answers for the below queries.

- After payment over paypal how I would get result for payment success or failure as there is success and cancel url and IPN in payflow. Kindly suggest.
- On each recurring how I would get result for payment success or failure?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid double testing you can use price for testing like 0,01. To create a recurring payment use this html form:

```
<form method="post" name="formName" id="submitThisForm" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" >
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="your@papypamail.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Your Membership" />
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1"> 
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="sra" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="SECURITYCODE" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="hidden" name="quantity" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="page going after payment" />
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="ITEM DESCRIPTION" />
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2" />
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="your_listener_file.php" />
```

When the user is cancel a membership, paypal will notify on "notify_url" - in your case this will be file your_listener_file.php. Inside the this file you must check paypal POST variable 'txn_type' = 'subscr_cancel'. There is a several important points:

1. You must validate the ipn transaction:

   ```
       $post           = array( 'cmd' => '_notify-validate' );
   foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
           $post[$key] = $value;
   }
   $c  = curl_init();
   curl_setopt_array($c, array(
       CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT  => 15,
       CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 15,
       CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 15,
       CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
       CURLOPT_POST            => TRUE,
       CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS      => $post,
   ));
   $res = curl_exec($c);
   curl_close($c);
   $res    = trim($res);

   if( $res != 'VERIFIED' ) {
       exit();
   }
   ```
2. Second - Check is the transaction exist in your database using the unique key. You must use Paypal POST variable 'custom'.
3. If the transaction exist, just make some simple check:

   ```
   if( !empty($_POST['txn_type']) && $_POST['txn_type'] == 'subscr_cancel' )
       $paypalData['approved'] = 0;
   ```

**Other way is to use paypal express checkout. I recommended this method. Here one simple (PHP) example:**

```
// Parameters for SetExpressCheckout, which will be sent to PayPal

$padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = 'Product description';
$padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . 
' $'.$product->price.'/month';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0']         = $padata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . 
' $'.$product->price.'/month';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']        = 'http://site_url/paypal/ipn';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC']            = $product->name;
$padata['RETURNURL']                        = 'http://site_url/paypal/returnurl';
$padata['CANCELURL']                        = 'http://site_url/paypal/cancelurl';

$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE']    = 'USD';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION']   = 'SALE';
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT'] = $product->price;
$padata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT']      = $product->price;
$padata['L_BILLINGTYPE0']            = 'RecurringPayments';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0']  = $product->name;
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0']= '322';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0']  = '1';
$padata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0']   = $product->price;


$paypal_data            = http_build_query($padata);
$httpParsedResponseAr   = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $paypal_data);

//Respond according to message we receive from Paypal
if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])){

    //Redirect user to PayPal store with Token received.
    $paypalurl ='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token='.$httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"].'';
    header('Location: '.$paypalurl);

}else{
    echo 'Error : '.urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["L_LONGMESSAGE0"]).'';


}
```

Page returnurl:

```
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']   = 'Recurring Description';
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0']    = $hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'] . ' $'.$pr->price.'/month';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0']         = $pr->name;
$hosteddata['PROFILEREFERENCE']                    = $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0'];
$hosteddata['PROFILESTARTDATE']                 = date('Y-m-d') . 'T' . date('H:i:s').'Z';
$hosteddata['SUBSCRIBERNAME']                    = $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['FIRSTNAME'] . ' ' . $GetExpressCheckoutDetails['LASTNAME'];
$hosteddata['TOKEN']                          = urlencode($_POST['token']);
$hosteddata['DESC']                               = $hosteddata['L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0'];
$hosteddata['AMT']                             = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['BILLINGPERIOD']                  = 'Month';
$hosteddata['BILLINGFREQUENCY']                  = '1';
$hosteddata['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES']                = '12';
$hosteddata['REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']        = '1';
$hosteddata['VERSION']                           = '74.0';
$hosteddata['MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS']              = '1';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0']           = '1';
$hosteddata['L_BILLINGTYPE0']                    = 'RecurringPayments';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0']  = 'Digital';
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0']         = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['INITAMT']                            = $pr->price;
$hosteddata['L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0']     = $pr->id;
$hosteddata['PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL']        = 'http://site_url/paypal/ipn';


$paypal_data = http_build_query($hosteddata);
$hosted_saas_response = $this->PPHttpPost('CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile', $paypal_data);
```

**I used a separate method to post parameters to paypal**

```
private function PPHttpPost( $methodName_, $nvpStr_ ) {

$api_username   = 'yourpaypal@email.com';
$api_password   = 'QWEQWEWQEQWEQEQWE';
$api_signature   = 'WQEQWEQWEQWEWQEQWEQWEQWEQWEQWE.cT';
$api_endpoint    = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
$version     = '124.0';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 
$nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$api_password&USER=$api_username&SIGNATURE=$api_signature&$nvpStr_";

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);
$httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
}

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
         }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {

        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $api_endpoint.");

    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;

}
```

Comment: Other way is to use paypal express checkout, I will add example with express checkout